# React js material ui problem box inside responsive drawer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui, drawer

[image]

I took the example on the documentation regarding the `Responsive drawer`.

As can be seen from the image, the part of the content at a certain height that depends on the context of it.

But I would like the background of the context as seen from the image to be the same.

I tried adding to the text box, either using `flex: 1` or`height: "100%"`, but nothing changes.

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsivedrawer-material-demo-forked-sqcipe?file=/demo.js)

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to make it work as expected is to assign a maximum height of [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts) (`height: 100vh`) to your box component.

```
...
<Box component="main" 
sx={{ 
  flexGrow: 1,
  p: 3, 
  width: { sm: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)` }, 
  height: '100vh', 
  color: "#fff", 
  backgroundColor: "#212121" 
}}>
  <Toolbar />
  <Typography paragraph>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  </Typography>
</Box>
...
```

**Working example:**

[image: Edit ResponsiveDrawer Material Demo (forked)]

**Note:** your solutions won't work because of the following:

- `height` property with a percentage value will be inherited from the parent element since the parent element `height` by default is `auto` (which is inherited from its parent too), so it won't work as expected.
- `flex` property won't work as expected because the `flex-direction` will be `row` by default. But it also won't work if you change it to `column` since the maximum height of the container is `auto` and it follows the same rule as above.

Comment: It seems to work, do you think there are other possible solutions?
In your opinion, is it normal that by default the height fits the content and doesn't take up all the space?

Comment: the white part the one under the black part, what element is it part of?
The parent component does not appear.

Comment: @Paul First of all the default behaviour of `height` attribute is [`content area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model#content_area) which means it will only grow as content grows. The other solution that I can offer is likely the same, you can add a custom `height` to the root element then make the children inherit the `height` from it.

Comment: @Paul And the white part is beneath the `<nav>` element, it filled the whole height because it used the  [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values), `display: flex` and `flex-direciton: column` with the `height: 100%` otherwise it won't fill the whole height.